# hold previous ajax response value into a jquery variable and add the value into next ajax response value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a program in which I can get price value using ajax and I want when I get price value next time the previous price value can add into current price value.

But the problem is when I get the current price and after I can get next price value then the previous price cannot hold it can override by next value and I cannot add the values

What is the solution please help me

**In JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('change','.searchAmount',function()
 {
     var id=$(this).attr("id");
     var amount=$('#'+id).val();

     var rate=$('#rate'+idd).val();
     var cgst=$('#cgstrate'+idd).val();
     var sgst=$('#sgstrate'+idd).val();


     $.ajax({
         url:"SellSameStateAmountChange.jsp",
         method:"post",
         dataType:'json',
         data:{amount:amount,rate:rate,cgst:cgst,sgst:sgst,qty:qty},
         cache:false,
         success:function(data)
         {
          var sum=0.0;  
          $('#rate'+idd).val(data.price); 
          sum+=data.amount;
          alert(sum);//Like this
         }
     });

     });
```

**In JSP**

```
<%-- 
    Document   : SellSameStateAmountChange
    Created on : Feb 12, 2018, 8:10:43 PM
    Author     : Lenovo
--%>

<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>

<%
     double amount=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("amount"));
     double rate=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("rate"));
     double cgst=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("cgst"));
     double sgst=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("sgst"));
     double qty=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("qty"));

     double gst=cgst+sgst;

     double changedRate=rate*qty;

     double price=amount-(gst/100)*changedRate;

     JSONObject json=new JSONObject();

     json.put("price",price);
     json.put("amount",amount);

     out.print(json.toString());



%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `var sum=0.0` outside the ajax callback and change event so that it doesn't get "reset" every time.

```
// Moved to here
var sum=0.0;  

$(document).on('change','.searchAmount',function()
{
 var id=$(this).attr("id");
 var amount=$('#'+id).val();

 var rate=$('#rate'+idd).val();
 var cgst=$('#cgstrate'+idd).val();
 var sgst=$('#sgstrate'+idd).val();



 $.ajax({
     url:"SellSameStateAmountChange.jsp",
     method:"post",
     dataType:'json',
     data:{amount:amount,rate:rate,cgst:cgst,sgst:sgst,qty:qty},
     cache:false,
     success:function(data)
     {

      // removed from here

      $('#rate'+idd).val(data.price); 
      sum+=data.amount;
      alert(sum);//Like this
     }
 });
});
```

Note that this generates a "global variable" which is generally frowned upon, so there are ways around this, such as using namespaces or storing the sum directly on the element.

eg:

```
// Moved to here
var sum=0.0;  

$(document).on('change','.searchAmount',function()
{
  // setup variables skipped for brevity
  $.ajax({
     url:"SellSameStateAmountChange.jsp",
     method:"post",
     dataType:'json',
     data:{amount:amount,rate:rate,cgst:cgst,sgst:sgst,qty:qty},
     cache:false,
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#rate'+idd).val(data.price); 

      var sum = $(this).data("sum") 
      sum+=data.amount;
      $(this).data("sum", sum);

      alert(sum);
     }
 });
});
```